# NVDA and JAWS Disable Input in Textarea

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader, nvda, accessibility

I have a form that has several input fields including a textarea for additional comment. When JAWS or NVDA is on, I am not able to type in the textarea.  However, it works fine when JAWS and NVDA are turned off. I added a role, but I still had the issue. Is there some other property that I am missing?

APP: Asp.net MVC 4
     jQuery 3.1
     Bootstrap 3.7

```
  <label aria-hidden="true">
    <span>Add a comment</span>
     @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.AddComment,new{ id = "AddComment", @rows="5",    
      @cols = "40" , @aria_multiline = "true", @class="form-control"})
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The aria-hidden="true" in the label was the cause of the issue. Once I realized and removed it, it worked.

```
<label>
    <span>Add a comment</span>
     @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.AddComment,new{ id = "AddComment", @rows="5",    
      @cols = "40" , @aria_multiline = "true", @class="form-control"})
 </label>
```